# Repurpose old laptop into wireless dock station

Tags: docking-station

Recently I bought laptop with limited connectivity options (no HDMI/Ethernet, not enough USB ports etc.). My idea is to make docking station out of old laptop. 
Is there any software which can share USB ports and external display via network connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Linux, you could use Xdmx (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/277293/extend-display-over-network-on-linux-with-vnc) answer) for display sharing and `usbip` for usb port sharing. You would need to do a decent amount of scripting to get this working seamlessly though.